# need information about my username and password

Tags: password, username

Just got my laptop and Ubuntu was already installed when I switched it on. I don't know my username nor password, no disk / paper was included. So I can't install applications or run this program normally. What can I do to learn a password? I even can't restart or switch off my device to change it.

Answer (score 0):

What would be the use of the password if anyone could read it? Of cause you can't. In your situation there are two ways:

1. Reinstall Ubuntu. I recommend it because this way you will both get all the settings right and be sure nobody left a nasty trick in your machine, intentionally or not.
2. Boot from live CD. Then chroot into your system and change passwd. [Here are instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery). If you follow them , keep in mind that your disk name may be different from `/dev/sda1`, use `lsblk` utility (in LiveCD) to  check.